# Matrix validation format

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, matrix

I am making page for matrix multiplication and I need to validate those matrices. Currently I have regex that accepts this format: `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` but it should accept this as well: `[[1,2,3]]`.

```
^\[(\[[\d+,\s*]+\],)+\[[\d+,]+]]$
```

What should I do? How it can match single array and group of them too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want something like this:

```
^\[?(?:(?:\[(?:(?:[0-9]{1,}\,?){1,})\])\,?){1,}\]?$
```

To match all these:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]
[[1,2,3]]
[[1],[2]]
```

Regex 101 here: https://regex101.com/r/tsS0G3/3